# Why is this form of acceptable, but the other form raises a type error?

Tags: haskell

While working through *Real World Haskell,* I tried to complete the palindrome exercise using the following code solution:

```
palin :: [a] -> [a]
palin list = list ++ rev list
    where rev list
           | null list = []
           | otherwise = rev (tail list) ++ (head list)
```

Which raised a "cannot construct an infinite type error. However, simply replacing the parenthesis around the head list with square brackets, and it works correctly, as demonstrated in the following example:

```
palin :: [a] -> [a]
palin list = list ++ rev list
    where rev list
           | null list = []
           | otherwise = rev (tail list) ++ [head list]
```

I don't really understand why it matters, nor do I understand what does the "cannot construct infinite type a = [a]" error means. Could someone explain this?

Comment: An expression of the form `(something)` **never** has the same type as the corresponding expression of the form `[something]`, where you simply replace the parentheses with square brackets. That *always* matters!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the last line, you are trying to append a non-list to a list. `head list` gives the first item of the list, which is type `a`. When you try to use `++` to append, you can't append something that isn't a list to a list. By appending `[head list]`, you are appending a list of 1 item to the other list. The `[]` construct the single item list in this case.

Answer (score 10):

Assume you are the type checker and you see a this:

```
(tail list) ++ (head list)
```

You know already, the `list is a list of something. So you start with:

```
list::[a]
```

then this must be true:

```
(tail list)::[a]
```

and this:

```
(head list)::a
```

But then there's `++ which wants both its arguments to have the *same* type. But this means, that

```
a == [a]
```

or by substitution:

```
a == [a] == [[a]] == [[[a]]] ...etc.
```

which is indeed an infinite type.

Answer (score 7):

`++` operator has type `[a] -> [a] -> [a]`, i.e. it takes two lists of some type and produces another list of the same type. OTOH `head` function has type `[a] -> a`, i.e. it takes a list of some type and returns a value of that type. In your first example `++` got `[a]` on the left hand and `a` on the right hand. Trying to unify these types type checker produces that error. In the second example you've constructed a single-element list from the result of `head` and it has type `[a]`, so type checker is happy.